# How does the Uniform Plumbing Code apply to me, for the purposes of home renovation?

Tags: texas, construction-law

According to my state, Texas, Occupations code, Chapter 1301. PLUMBERS, it says in
SEC. 1301.255. Adoption of Plumbing codes,

> **Section 1301.255 adopts the Uniform Plumbing Code** and the International Code Council's International Plumbing Code as they existed on May 31, 2001. The statute notes that the Texas State Board of Plumbing Examiners may adopt later versions of this code.
>
> **As of June 2021, the 2018 edition of the Uniform Plumbing Code** and the 2018 edition of the International Code Council's International Plumbing Code **have been adopted by the State Board's Rule 367.2 in Title 22 of the Texas Administrative Code.**
>
> Rule 367.2 also adopts codes incorporated by reference within the 2018 International Plumbing Code, which include the International Code Council's 2018 International Fuel Gas Code and the 2018 International Residential Code.
>
> See the text of Rule 367.2 for details.

Does this bind me as a homeowner doing personal home renovations, or just plumbers for hire?

Comment: There's a fully readable, albeit annoyingly watermarked, free version at https://epubs.iapmo.org/2018/UPC/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Texas Occupation code is irrelevant to you since you are not in the occupation of being a plumber. Instead, as a homeowner, you are subject to your local building codes. [This](https://www.houstonpermittingcenter.org/media/6126/download?inline) is the Houston Plumbing Code. You particularly need to pay attention to the obligations and exemptions of homeowners. §102.10 says

> In accordance with the Plumbing License Law, this code shall not
> prevent any homeowner from installing and maintaining plumbing in a
> building owned and occupied by him as his homestead if done in
> compliance with the requirements of all applicable state-adopted codes
> and ordinances of this jurisdiction. Such privilege does not grant the
> right to violate any of the provisions of this code or state-adopted
> codes, nor shall it be construed as exempting any such property owner
> from obtaining a permit and paying the required fees therefor, except
> for work that is exempt from permitting under this code.

In other words, if a permit is required, you must get the permit and pay the fee, except not all work requires a permit.

§104.2 specifies what constitutes exempt work:

> A permit shall not be required for the following: (1) The stopping of
> leaks in drains, or soil, waste, or vent pipe, provided, however, that
> if a trap, drain pipe, or soil, waste, or vent pipe becomes defective
> and it becomes necessary to remove and replace the same it with new
> material, the same it shall be considered as new work and for which a
> permit shall be procured and inspection made as provided in this code.
> (2) The clearing of stoppages, including the removal and
> reinstallation of bathroom or kitchen faucets or water closets, or the
> repairing of leaks in pipes, valves, or fixtures, provided such
> repairs do not involve or require the replacement or rearrangement of
> valves, pipes, or fixtures. Exemption from the permit requirements of
> this code shall not be deemed to grant authorization for work to be
> done in violation of the provisions of the this code or other laws or
> ordinances of this jurisdiction. This section shall be construed in a
> manner that is consistent with the Plumbing License Law, and no
> provision herein shall be construed to exempt work for which a permit
> is required to be obtained from this jurisdiction.

The main reason to care about this document is that municipalities are entitled to and often do modify the "Uniform" codes, and it is pointless to argue "The Code says..." when their reply is "We require that...".

Comment: Really good answer. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can purchase your own copy of the UPC at just about any outlet that sells books including Amazon:  [https://www.amazon.com/2018-Uniform-Plumbing-Code-Tabs/dp/1944366075](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1944366075)
2. Yes, your local AHJ (agency having jurisdiction) almost certainly has adopted this code or something very similar to it and you need to pull a permit, have the required inspections, and follow the code with any modifications or changes.

Comment: "Any" modifications or changes?  How certain of that are you?

Answer (score 3):

I've only done very minor plumbing work in Texas (like replacing a faucet). Rather than trying to interpret all the exceptions that may exist, such as for homeowners or for minor projects, the easiest thing to do is locate the office that issues plumbing permits in your area and ask them. For example, [Houston Public Works has a web page for homeowners who want to pull a permit](https://www.houstonpermittingcenter.org/hpwcode1099).

Also, the codes can be very difficult to understand. I'd suggest looking on the internet to get a sense of what commercially published handbooks are considered reliable. Then visit a plumbing supply house and see if they have any on sale. Make sure whatever you get is recent and says it follows the appropriate version of the UPC.